# InputScope for coordinates (minus needed)

Tags: windows-phone-7, coordinates, inputscope

I need have a textbox where user can input latitude and longitude, eg.
51.499167, -0.124722 for Palace of Westminster.

The problem is, that InputScope numerical hasn't `Minus` char.

Has some the same problem and has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of these:

> AddressStreet*, CurrencyAmountAndSymbol, CurrencyChinese,
>   PostalAddress, PostalCode, Time, TelephoneAreaCode,
>   TelephoneCountryCode, TelephoneLocalNumber, TelephoneNumber

They all display numbers with the minus sign as shown on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393998%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: TelephoneNumber works fine. There are *, # and space chars but I know that there is no way to remove those chars. Thanks a lot